# How to handle multiline and single line logs with one Fluend and Elasticsearch

Tags: fluentd

In my cluster I have set up [Fluentd DaemonSet for Elasticsearch](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset). Its working fine and I can see logs in Kibana. We have different pods/containers. Some are Java, Python, Nginx, etc.

The problem at the moment is, for multiline logs (Java), in case of an exception each line will be pushed to Elasticsearch as a separate log. Instead, it should identify and push multiples lines of a same log as one log statement. I know I can use [multiline parse](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/multiline) but the problem is on the cluster I have many other containers which do not log multiline logs. For example we have Nginx pods/containers.

I need to configure Fluentd to handle all types of logs, multiline and single line. What is the solution in this case? How should I configure Fluentd to handle both cases?

Comment: To make all the logs uniform, can you not transform a multiline log into a single line?

Comment: Yes, I think that will work. If I substitute all line breaks with something else is there a way to reverse the process in Kibana so that when someone is looking at the logs they can make sense of it

Comment: Not sure about that. I was avoiding the routing of events by rewriting tags for Java exceptions and the rest of the logs. Looks like you might have to resort to that. BTW, have you thought about this?

Comment: I found [fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions). I'm going to test it.